# How to change ImageView (iOS) using an "if" statement?

Tags: objective-c, ios

The user see one image, and it should change to another according to the if statment (true or false) - not sure how to do it in objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
imageView.image = (your true-or-false expression) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"bar.png"];
```

If `true`, you get `foo.png` for your image, otherwise `bar.png`.

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
if gender == "Male" {
        cell.profileView.image = UIImage(named: "img")
    }
    
   else if gender == "Female" {
        cell.profileView.image = UIImage(named: "woman-avatar")
    }
    
    else if gender == "other" {
        cell.profileView.image = UIImage(named: "Transgender")
    }
```

Comment: if you want to set your UIImageView dynamically. you can use above mention logics. you can use local UIImage(image name) array or you can use API response data that you received through Json.

Comment: This code implement on UITableview

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).